# Multiple default gateway issue on a laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet

Its been a long time but i'm back.

I do have a  Linksys WAG120N brand of wireless router at home which allows me share internet connection between three laptops either wired or in a wireless manner.

Our home has two floors. When i get close to the router i  prefer going wired through my own laptop. On that laptop, i assign IP addresses for wired adapter and Default Gateway.However, once i have to go to lower floor, my connection poses issues.

When i lay down on my bed on the lower floor, I try to connect to my router which is located on the upper. Most likely i fail the first time. DG 'remains the same' on the Ethernet adapter and i attempt
to go through same DG on the wireless adapter. That time, Windows warns me with 'Multiple Gateways configured....'and i am unable to connect to the Internet unless i remove it from the Ethernet Adapter.

Question 1 ) i assign the exact same number which is 192.168.1.1 (default value for Cisco routers)
          so, how could this be recognized as Multiple?

Question 2 ) As far as i know, only one DG can be configured for each network adapter on one PC. When its the same number, how could this be a problem and really breaks my connection which is happening whenever i do it on the lower floor?

Comment: Although they refer to the same IP address, they result in the computer doing very different things. For example, your computer has a different hardware address for each physical interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a test to improve your experience, try the following:

1. When your using wireless, disable the ethernet card.
2. When your done using wireless, disable the wireless before connecting the ethernet cable.
3. Switch on the ethernet card.